# Make a SQL query with the WHERE clause accepting array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of six elements (`$categories = array('dinner','casual','wedding')`) and I would like to make a SQL query that would look like this:

`SELECT *
FROM produts
WHERE id = /* values of array $categories... eg. (dinner || casual || wedding) */`

Comment: Are you trying to get the results for all items in the array in the same query or were you looking for separate queries for each item?

Comment: I want the results in the same query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$conditions = '';

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    $conditions[] = " id = '".$cat."'";
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM produts WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $conditions);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must to use IN instead WHERE.

Comment: *"You must to use IN instead WHERE."* - You still need to use WHERE with IN() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in as to what the OP wants to do here.

Comment: How would you apply your idea to the question example?